# How to surround multiple-element arguments with parantheses?

Tags: macros, conditionals

A command without brackets specifying the argument takes just the first element after it as an argument, so that `a^bc` will only have the superscripted b. I would like to exploit this with typeset functions in LaTex like `\ln`,`\sin`, and so on. In the case of just one argument, like `\ln{a}bc` or `\ln abc`, the function would not be typeset with parentheses. In the case of multiple elements in an argument, like `\ln{abc}`, there would be parentheses typeset around the argument, the triple product shown.

The motivation for this is the variable need for parentheses in logarithms and readibility of code. For example, I could write `\ln{a + b}` to unambigiously refer to the logarithm of a sum, and `\ln ab` to unambigiously refer to the logarithm of a product (by most conventions). Since the logarithm or other mathematical operator is only a standalone typeset, the spurious argument in the absence of bracketing (`\ln ab` would be equivalent to `\ln{a}b`) doesn't have an effect on the typesetting. This has an advantage in readibility, for example, contrast `\ln\left(a + \frac bc\right)` and `\ln{a + \frac bc}`.

How do I define a command which recognizes how many elements are in the argument and would add parentheses if there are more than one?

Comment: With xparse and mleftright loaded, you can do `\let\lnop\ln \RenewDocumentCommand\ln{d()}{\lnop\IfValueT{#1}{\mleft(#1\mright)}}`. That way you use `\ln ab` and `\ln(a+b)` and `\ln(a+\frac bc)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution uses `\@gobble` with a simple if-statement to test if a macro argument contains more than one character. There might be better ways to do this. Once you have a macro that adds parentheses on certain conditions, you can add it to any function with `\g@addto@macro`.

Here is a MWE with examples you mentioned:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addparentheses}[1]{%
    \if\@gobble#1\relax\relax#1\else\left(#1\right)\fi
}
\g@addto@macro{\ln}{\addparentheses}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Tests:

$\ln ab$

$\ln{a}b$

$\ln{a + b}$

$\ln{a + \frac bc}$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: ln with or without parentheses]